# Как сделать проверку на бан участников на аиограм

Tags: python, aiogram

Как сделать, чтобы если админ (не владелец канала) банил больше 15 человек, то бот снимал его с прав администратора? Таким образом, я хочу сделать бота "антисливщика". Нужно, чтобы работал и в чате и в канале. Я использую модуль aiogram. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Держать изменения(бан участников) в БД по времени. После каждого бана проверять сколько человек забанено за период, допустим, 1 минуту.